# Liquibase support for multiple schmas in a multitenant environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi tenant environment with shared database and separated schema for every tenant.

My tenant table is as follows:

```
id|tenant_id|tenant_schema_name|company_flg|
--|---------|------------------|-----------|
```

Also there is an app_roles table where is plan to seed some data using the liquibase script itself.

The app_roles table is as follows:

```
role_id|role_nm   |
-------|----------|
      1|ROLE_ADMIN|
      2|ROLE_USER |
```

Bean which runs liquibase script for all the tenants present in the defaultSchema (which is the global schema) is:

```
@Bean
public MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibaseMt(DataSource dataSource)
        throws SQLException {
    MultiTenantSpringLiquibase multiTenantSpringLiquibase = new MultiTenantSpringLiquibase();
    multiTenantSpringLiquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);

    Statement stmt = null;
    stmt = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT tenant_schema_name FROM {defaultSchema}.tenant" ;
    sql = sql.replace("{defaultSchema}", AllConstants.defaultSchema);
    ResultSet rs = stmt
            .executeQuery(sql);
    List<String> schemas = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String schemaName = rs.getString("tenant_schema_name");
        logger.info(schemaName);
        dataSource.getConnection().createStatement()
                .executeUpdate("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS " + schemaName);
        schemas.add(schemaName);
    }
    multiTenantSpringLiquibase.setSchemas(schemas);
    multiTenantSpringLiquibase.setChangeLog(AllConstants.liquibasePath);
    multiTenantSpringLiquibase.setShouldRun(true);      
    if(schemas.isEmpty()) {
        multiTenantSpringLiquibase.setDefaultSchema(AllConstants.defaultSchema);
    }
    return multiTenantSpringLiquibase;
}
```

The above mentioned bean creates schema for every tenant and executes liquibase for every schema for the tenant.

Below is my liquibase script:

db.changelog-master.yaml:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- include:
    file: db/changelog/changes/db.changelog-create-v1.yml
- include:
    file: db/changelog/changes/db.changelog-seed-v1.yml
```

db.changelog-create-v1.yml:

```
databaseChangeLog:
              
- changeSet: 
    id: author-create-3
    author: author
    preCondition:
      onFail: MARK_RAN
      not:
        tableExists: 
          tableName: APP_ROLES
    changes:
    - createTable: 
        tableName: APP_ROLES
        columns:
          - column:
              name: ROLE_ID
              constraints:
                primaryKey: true
                nullable: false
                primaryKeyName: APP_ROLE_PK
              type: INTEGER
          - column:
              name: ROLE_NM
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
   
- changeSet:
    id: author-create-7
    author: author
    preConditions:
      onFail: MARK_RAN
      not:
        sequenceExists:
          sequenceName: TENANT_SEQ
    changes:
    - createSequence:
         sequenceName: TENANT_SEQ
         startValue: 1
         minValue: 1
         incrementBy: 1

- changeSet: 
    id: author-create-8
    author: author
    preCondition:
      onFail: MARK_RAN
      not:
        tableExists: 
          tableName: TENANT
    changes:
    - createTable: 
        tableName: TENANT
        columns:
          - column:
              name: ID
              constraints:
                primaryKey: true
                nullable: false
                primaryKeyName: TENANT_PK
              type: INTEGER
          - column:
              name: TENANT_ID
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: TENANT_SCHEMA_NAME
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: COMPANY_FLG
              type: BOOLEAN
```

db.changelog-seed-v1.yml:

```
databaseChangeLog:
    
- changeSet:
    id: author-seed-1
    author: author
    preConditions:
        onFail: MARK_RAN
        sqlCheck:
            expectedResult: 0
            sql: select count(*) from app_roles;
    changes:
    - sql:
        sql: INSERT INTO app_roles (role_id, role_nm) VALUES (1, 'ROLE_ADMIN');
             INSERT INTO app_roles (role_id, role_nm) VALUES (2, 'ROLE_USER');
```

The problematic part here is the create scripts runs for every tenant successfully and creates required tables for me but the seed script seeds data only for the default schema and for all other preconditions it find 2 rows from the default schema and bypasses the seeding part for every tenant.

Here, While application starts for the first time, default schema (global schema) is created. I create tenant using sql query in the global schema and restart the application so that liquibase script runs for all the sql inserted tenants.

How do I programatically logical solution would be to programatically asking the seed script to run against a particular schema but I have no idea how to do that.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

I have referred the [link](https://github.com/rmsantana/poc-multi-tenant/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rafael/Application.java) to create the bean mentioned above.

Comment: What DB platform are you using?  If it were mysql, you could change the url to a variable like: url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${schema} in your liquibase.properties file and then call liquibase via your bean or CLI with the value.  Here's how it would look in cli: 
liquibase -Dschema=someSchema update

Comment: @ronak, I am using postgreSQL as DB platform

Comment: you could try using: url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:<port>/${schema}

Comment: Also this may help as well: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-i-automated-database-schema-migrations-in-a-multi-tenant-database-model-using-liquibase-f75f9683ee06 and

Comment: I am facing an issue in multi-tenant application, when I create a database and run liquibase on it, the application restarts I don't know why. Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: @HafizHamza, can you please show the code or error (if you are getting any). It would be difficult to judge the situation without any hint.

Comment: I ask question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71051578/multi-tenant-spring-boot-application-restarts-when-i-run-liquibase-on-newly-cr