# Multi Tenant - Spring Boot application restarts when I run Liquibase on newly created database

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, multi-tenant

I am facing a problem with my multi-tenant application. When I run liquibase on a newly created database for the first time, the application (microservice) gets restarted but the tables get created. The interesting thing is next time I run liquibase on that database (in which tables are created), the application doesn't restart.

I observe that application is restarting on `liquibase.update((String) null);`

Here is datasource resolver class (`AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl`)

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class DynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProvider extends 
AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -460277105706399638L;

    private static final String TENANT_POOL_NAME_SUFFIX = "DataSource";

    private final CryptionService cryptionService;

    private final DataSourceCacheService dataSourceCacheService;

    private final DynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantSpringLiquibase dynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantSpringLiquibase;

    @Autowired
    public DynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProvider(CryptionService cryptionService, DataSourceCacheService dataSourceCacheService, DynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantSpringLiquibase dynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantSpringLiquibase) {
        this.cryptionService = cryptionService;
        this.dataSourceCacheService = dataSourceCacheService;
        this.dynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantSpringLiquibase = dynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantSpringLiquibase;
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
        // There will be no Default datasource
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        try {
            DataSource dataSource = dataSourceCacheService.getDataSource(tenantIdentifier);

            log.info("Initializing Liquibase for tenant " + tenantIdentifier);
            dynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantSpringLiquibase.runLiquibase(dataSource); // This will run liquibase            
            return dataSource;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new TenantNotFoundException("Failed to load DataSource for tenant:" + tenantIdentifier, tenantIdentifier);
        }
    }
}
```

Run liquibase on selected data source by using the class (`DynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantSpringLiquibase.class`)

```
/**
 * Based on MultiTenantSpringLiquibase, this class provides Liquibase support for
 * multi-tenancy based on a dynamic collection of DataSources.
 */
@Getter
@Setter
@Slf4j
public class DynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantSpringLiquibase implements InitializingBean, ResourceLoaderAware {

    @Autowired
    private CryptionService cryptionService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("tenantLiquibaseProperties")
    private LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties;

    @Value("${multitenancy.tenant.entityManager.packages}")
    private String entityPackages;

    private TenantCommonProperties tenantCommonProperties;

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        log.info("DynamicDataSources based multitenancy enabled");
    }

    public void runLiquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
        try {
            SpringLiquibase liquibase = this.getSpringLiquibase(dataSource);
            liquibase.afterPropertiesSet(); // It will call performUpdate method
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to run Liquibase: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public SpringLiquibase getSpringLiquibase(DataSource liquibaseDataSource) throws SQLException {
        YomoDiffSpringLiquibase springLiquibase = new YomoDiffSpringLiquibase();
        springLiquibase.setDataSource(liquibaseDataSource);

        springLiquibase.setChangeLog(liquibaseProperties.getChangeLog());
        springLiquibase.setContexts("development,test,production");

        springLiquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseDataSource.getConnection().getCatalog());
        springLiquibase.setLiquibaseSchema(liquibaseDataSource.getConnection().getCatalog());

        springLiquibase.setLiquibaseTablespace(liquibaseProperties.getLiquibaseTablespace());
        springLiquibase.setDatabaseChangeLogTable(liquibaseProperties.getDatabaseChangeLogTable());
        springLiquibase.setDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(liquibaseProperties.getDatabaseChangeLogLockTable());
        springLiquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());

        springLiquibase.setShouldRun(true);

        springLiquibase.setLabels(liquibaseProperties.getLabels());
        springLiquibase.setChangeLogParameters(liquibaseProperties.getParameters());
        springLiquibase.setRollbackFile(liquibaseProperties.getRollbackFile());
        springLiquibase.setTestRollbackOnUpdate(liquibaseProperties.isTestRollbackOnUpdate());

        springLiquibase.setMultilanguage(true);
        springLiquibase.setPackagesToScan(entityPackages);
        return springLiquibase;
    }

}
```

`liquibase.afterPropertiesSet` method will call `performUpdate` method I have override this method.

```
@Override
    public void performUpdate(Liquibase pLiquibase) throws LiquibaseException {


        long startTime = 0;
        long endTime = 0;

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Database referenceDatabase = null;
        Database comparisonDatabase = null;
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        CompareControl compareControl;
        DiffOutputControl diffOutputControl = null;
        Liquibase liquibase = null;
        DiffResult diffResult = null;

        String YOMOAPP_CATALOG = pLiquibase.getDatabase().getDefaultCatalogName();



        if (!isEmpty(this.packagesToScan)) {
            throw new LiquibaseException("PackagesToScan is not set");
        }

        if (this.ml) {
            //this.packagesToScan += ",de.yomobit.ym.core.domain";
        }

        try {
            ArrayList<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] parts = this.packagesToScan.split(",");
            Reflections reflections = null;
            ConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = null;
            for (String part : parts) {
                configBuilder =
                        new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().includePackage(part))
                                .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(part))
                                .setScanners(
                                        new TypeAnnotationsScanner(),
                                        new MethodParameterScanner(),
                                        new MethodAnnotationsScanner(),
                                        new SubTypesScanner(),
                                        new FieldAnnotationsScanner()
                                );

                //reflections = new Reflections(part);
                reflections = new Reflections(configBuilder);


                Set<Field> fields = reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(javax.persistence.JoinTable.class);
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                        if (annotation instanceof javax.persistence.JoinTable) {
                            javax.persistence.JoinTable table = (javax.persistence.JoinTable) annotation;
                            log.debug("joinTable:" + table.name());
                            tableNames.add(table.name());
                        }
                    }
                }




                fields = reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides.class);
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                        if (annotation instanceof javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides) {
                            javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides table = (javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides) annotation;
                            AssociationOverride[] associationOverrides = table.value();
                            for(AssociationOverride associationOverride: associationOverrides) {
                                log.debug("assof:" + associationOverride.joinTable().name());
                                tableNames.add(associationOverride.joinTable().name());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                fields = reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(javax.persistence.CollectionTable.class);
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                        if (annotation instanceof javax.persistence.CollectionTable) {
                            javax.persistence.CollectionTable table = (javax.persistence.CollectionTable) annotation;
                            log.debug("collection:" + table.name());
                            tableNames.add(table.name());
                        }
                    }
                }




                Set<Class<?>> typesAnnotatedWith = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
                for (Class<?> clazz : typesAnnotatedWith) {
                    String name = clazz.getName();
                    //log.info(name);
                    Annotation[] annotations = clazz.getDeclaredAnnotations();
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                        //log.info(annotation.toString());
                        //log.info(annotation.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                        if (annotation instanceof javax.persistence.Table) {
                            javax.persistence.Table table = (javax.persistence.Table) annotation;
                            log.debug("table:" + table.name());
                            tableNames.add(table.name());
                        }
                    }
                }



                typesAnnotatedWith = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides.class);
                for (Class<?> clazz : typesAnnotatedWith) {
                    String name = clazz.getName();
                    Annotation[] annotations = clazz.getDeclaredAnnotations();
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                        if (annotation instanceof javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides) {
                            javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides table = (javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides) annotation;
                            AssociationOverride[] associationOverrides = table.value();
                            for(AssociationOverride associationOverride: associationOverrides) {
                                log.debug("AssociationOverride:" + associationOverride.joinTable().name());
                                tableNames.add(associationOverride.joinTable().name());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            /*
            log.info("Subtypes of BaseEntity :");
            Set<Class<? extends BaseEntity>> subTypesOf = reflections.getSubTypesOf(BaseEntity.class);
            for (Class<?> clazz : subTypesOf)
                String name = clazz.getName();
                log.info(name);
                Annotation[] annotations = clazz.getDeclaredAnnotations();
               for(java.lang.annotation.Annotation annotation: annotations)
                    //log.info(annotation.toString());
                    log.info(annotation.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                    if (annotation instanceof  javax.persistence.Table) {
                        javax.persistence.Table table = (javax.persistence.Table) annotation;
                        log.info("Table:" + table.name());
                    }
               }

            }
            */
            }


            String diffTypes = "tables,views,columns,indexes,foreignkeys,primarykeys,uniqueconstraints";

            String referenceDefaultCatalogName = YOMOAPP_CATALOG;
            String referenceDefaultSchemaName = YOMOAPP_SCHEMA;
            boolean outputDefaultCatalog = false;
            boolean outputDefaultSchema = false;
            String databaseChangeLogTableName = null;
            String databaseChangeLogLockTableName = null;
            String liquibaseSchemaName = YOMOAPP_SCHEMA;
            String liquibaseCatalogName = YOMOAPP_CATALOG;
            String defaultCatalogName = YOMOAPP_CATALOG;
            String defaultSchemaName = YOMOAPP_SCHEMA;




            List<ResourceAccessor> openers = new ArrayList<ResourceAccessor>();
            openers.add(new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(classLoader));
            ResourceAccessor fileOpener = new CompositeResourceAccessor(openers);

            comparisonDatabase = pLiquibase.getDatabase();
            comparisonDatabase.setDefaultCatalogName(defaultCatalogName);
            comparisonDatabase.setDefaultSchemaName(defaultSchemaName);
            comparisonDatabase.setOutputDefaultCatalog(outputDefaultCatalog);
            comparisonDatabase.setOutputDefaultSchema(outputDefaultSchema);
            comparisonDatabase.setLiquibaseCatalogName(liquibaseCatalogName);
            comparisonDatabase.setLiquibaseSchemaName(liquibaseSchemaName);
            if (databaseChangeLogTableName != null) {
                if (databaseChangeLogLockTableName != null) {
                    comparisonDatabase.setDatabaseChangeLogLockTableName(databaseChangeLogLockTableName);
                } else {
                    comparisonDatabase.setDatabaseChangeLogLockTableName(databaseChangeLogTableName + "LOCK");
                }
            }


            String referenceUrl = "hibernate:spring:" + this.packagesToScan + "?dialect="
                    //+ MySQL5Dialect.class.getName()
                    + PostgreSQL9Dialect.class.getName();
            /*
            String referenceUrl = "hibernate:spring:"
                    + this.packagesToScan
                    + "?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy";
            */
            String referenceDriver = "liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver";
            referenceDatabase = new HibernateSpringPackageDatabase();
            try {
                DatabaseConnection databaseConnection = new JdbcConnection(new HibernateConnection(referenceUrl, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor()));
//                DatabaseConnection databaseConnection = (DatabaseConnection)new HibernateConnection(referenceUrl, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor());
                referenceDatabase.setConnection(databaseConnection);
            } catch (Throwable ue) {
                //ue.printStackTrace();
            }


            /*
            referenceDatabase = CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor()
                    ,referenceUrl
                    , null, null
                    ,referenceDriver
                    , null, null
                    , false, false
                    , null
                    , null, null
                    , null, null
                    , null, null);
*/
            referenceDatabase.setDefaultCatalogName(referenceDefaultCatalogName);
            referenceDatabase.setDefaultSchemaName(referenceDefaultSchemaName);
            referenceDatabase.setOutputDefaultCatalog(outputDefaultCatalog);
            referenceDatabase.setOutputDefaultSchema(outputDefaultSchema);
            referenceDatabase.setLiquibaseCatalogName(liquibaseCatalogName);
            referenceDatabase.setLiquibaseSchemaName(liquibaseSchemaName);
            if (databaseChangeLogTableName != null) {
                referenceDatabase.setDatabaseChangeLogTableName(databaseChangeLogTableName);
                if (databaseChangeLogLockTableName != null) {
                    referenceDatabase.setDatabaseChangeLogLockTableName(databaseChangeLogLockTableName);
                } else {
                    referenceDatabase.setDatabaseChangeLogLockTableName(databaseChangeLogTableName + "LOCK");
                }
            }




            CompareControl.ComputedSchemas computedSchemas = CompareControl.computeSchemas(YOMOAPP_SCHEMA
                    , YOMOAPP_SCHEMA
                    , YOMOAPP_SCHEMA
                    , defaultCatalogName
                    , defaultSchemaName
                    , referenceDefaultCatalogName
                    , referenceDefaultSchemaName
                    , comparisonDatabase);


            CompareControl.SchemaComparison[] finalSchemaComparisons = computedSchemas.finalSchemaComparisons = new CompareControl.SchemaComparison[]{new CompareControl.SchemaComparison(new CatalogAndSchema(referenceDefaultCatalogName, referenceDefaultSchemaName), new CatalogAndSchema(defaultCatalogName, defaultSchemaName))};
            compareControl = new CompareControl(finalSchemaComparisons, StringUtil.trimToNull(diffTypes));


            boolean includeCatalog = false;
            boolean includeSchema = false;
            boolean includeTablespace = false;
            diffOutputControl = new DiffOutputControl(includeCatalog, includeSchema, includeTablespace, finalSchemaComparisons);
            for (CompareControl.SchemaComparison schema : finalSchemaComparisons) {
                diffOutputControl.addIncludedSchema(schema.getReferenceSchema());
                diffOutputControl.addIncludedSchema(schema.getComparisonSchema());
            }


            liquibase = new Liquibase(new DatabaseChangeLog(), fileOpener, referenceDatabase);
            diffResult = liquibase.diff(referenceDatabase, comparisonDatabase, compareControl);
            removeDatabaseChangeLog(diffResult);
            listOrRemoveDatabaseChangedObjects(diffResult, tableNames);
            listOrRemoveDatabaseMissingObjects(diffResult, tableNames);
            listOrRemoveDatabaseUnexpectedObjects(diffResult, tableNames);

            DiffToChangeLog diffToChangeLog = new DiffToChangeLog(diffResult, diffOutputControl);
            CustomXMLChangeLogSerializer customXMLChangeLogSerializer = new CustomXMLChangeLogSerializer();
            diffToChangeLog.setChangeSetAuthor(YOMOAPP_SCHEMA);
            List<ChangeSet> changeSets = diffToChangeLog.generateChangeSets();
            // If no changes do nothing
            if (changeSets.size() != 0) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(out, true, "UTF-8");
                customXMLChangeLogSerializer.write(changeSets, printStream);
                printStream.flush();
                printStream.close();
                String changeLogString = out.toString("UTF-8");
                if (changeLogString != null) {
                    File outFile = null;
                    try {
                        outFile= ResourceUtils.getFile(this.getChangeLog());
                    }  catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
                        outFile = ResourceUtils.getFile(new URL(this.getChangeLog()));
                    }
                    OutputStream outChangeLog = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    outChangeLog.write(changeLogString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    outChangeLog.close();



                    /*
                    File outFile = File.createTempFile("db-changelog", ".xml");
                    outFile.deleteOnExit();
                    OutputStream outChangeLog = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    outChangeLog.write(changeLogString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    outChangeLog.close();
                     */

                    /*
                    String testPath = classLoader.getResource(CHANGELOG_FOLER).getPath();
                    File f = new File("/maven");
                    if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()){
                        f = new File ("/maven" + File.separator + CHANGELOG_FOLER);
                        if (!f.exists()){
                            f.mkdir();
                        }
                        testPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    }
                    f = null;
                    String changeLogName = "db-changelog-" + calculateNextSequence(testPath) + ".xml";
                    File changelogFile = new File(testPath + File.separator + changeLogName);
                    String diffChangeLogFile = changelogFile.getAbsolutePath();

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(changelogFile);
                    IOUtils.write(changeLogString, fw);
                    IOUtils.close(fw);
                     */

                    //log.debug("the db-changelog file '{}' has been generated", changelogFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    //liquibase = new Liquibase(diffChangeLogFile, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), comparisonDatabase);
                    //liquibase.update("development");


                    log.debug("the db-changelog file '{}' has been generated", outFile.toString());
                    System.out.println("File.listRoots():" + File.listRoots());
                    liquibase = new Liquibase(outFile.toString(), new FileSystemResourceAccessor(File.listRoots()), comparisonDatabase);
                    //StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                    //liquibase.update((String) null, stringWriter);
                    liquibase.update((String) null); // Here application will restart if database doesn't have tables

                    comparisonDatabase.commit();
                    referenceDatabase.commit();
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (referenceDatabase != null) {
                try {
                    referenceDatabase.close();
                } catch (DatabaseException e) {
                    log.error("Failed to close the reference database", e);
                }
            }


            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000");
            log.info("YomoDiffSpringLiquibase took " + formatter.format((endTime - startTime) / 1000d) + " seconds to execute liquibase changes");
        }

    }
```

Currently, I am creating only one table

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tenants")
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = false)
public class Tenant extends BaseEntity {

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true, length = 100)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String tenantId;

    @Column(name = "db", columnDefinition = "Varchar(255)")
    private String db;

    @Column(name = "url", columnDefinition = "Varchar(255)")
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "username", columnDefinition = "Varchar(100)")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", columnDefinition = "Varchar(100)")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "driver_class", columnDefinition = "Varchar(255)")
    private String driverClass;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

}
```

BaseEntity.class

```
@Data
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@MappedSuperclass
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ToString.Exclude
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @Version
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    protected long version;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    protected Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date modifiedDate;

    public void clearBaseInfo() {
        version = 0L;
        createdDate = null;
        modifiedDate = null;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        createdDate = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        modifiedDate = new Date();
    }

}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not